# Keras Input raises value error when dimensioons match

Tags: python, keras

I am starting to develop a model and am getting stuck with dimensions.  My X_train and Y_train are numpy arrays of shape `(65337, 19)`

```
Input_1= Input(shape=(19,))
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(Input_1)

out1 = Dense(1,  activation='linear')(x)
out2 = Dense(1,  activation='linear')(x)
...
out19 = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x)
model = Model(inputs=Input_1, outputs=[out1,out2,out3,out4,out5,out6,
                                  out7,out8,out9,out10,out11,out12,
                                  out13,out14,out15,out16,out17,out18,out19])
model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = 'mse')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=5)
```

When I run this, I get the value error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 19 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1
>   arrays:

Looking at other questions here, it seems using `.fit(np.array(X_train) , np.array(y_train)` has helped some, but I get the same error (which makes sense, since it tells me I have an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting 19 differents outputs, so you need to feed to you network with the 19 slices of your array of labels :

```
model.fit(X_train,[y_train[:,0], y_train[:,1], y_train[:,2],[...], y_train[:, 18]] , epochs=5)
```

Comment: That raises V`alueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_316 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (19,)`  But should I just use the slices?  like [y_train[:,1],....y_train[:,19])

Comment: Using the slices removed the error.  Thanks for the help (if you edit the answer I will accept it)